# ¿Como detener la ejecucion de setInterval() la cual fue ejecutada mediante onLoad()?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Hola compañeros se me ha presentado un problema bastante molesto y es el siguiente: tengo una pagina toda hecha en ajax y jquery y tengo diferentes menus; y por ejemplo al entrar al primer menu, dentro del codigo HTML tengo una imagen con un metodo onLoad de Javascript que me carga una funcion, la cual ejecuta otra funcion llamada load() en un intervalo de 20 segundos:

pagina.php

```
...
     <img src="../images/calendario-semanal.png" alt="" border="0" onload="refresh_automatico();" /> 
...
```

sript.js

```
function refresh_automatico(){

        $(document).ready(function(){
        clearInterval(refreshId);
                 var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
                     load();
                 }, 20000 );
            });
}
```

Hasta ahi todo perfecto, apenas entro a pagina.php, el script se ejecuta automatico refrescandose cada 20 segundos, pero al pasar a otra pagina veo que se sigue ejecutando y al volver a pagina.php noto que se duplican las llamadas y ya no son 20 segundos sino que se ejecuta muchas veces.
Como hago para detener esa ejecucion al clickear en otra pagina de mi proyecto.

Muchas gracias muchachos, les agradeceria en el alma su ayuda.

Bendiciones

Comment: Buen día, lo que buscas es que tu función se ejecute solo cuando se carga una determinada página?

Comment: es correcto @LuiscYm, eso es lo que busco, porque cuando paso a otra pagina aun se sigue ejecutando y asi no me sirve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para controlar que funciones se ejecutan dependiendo de la página en la que estas actualmente puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
// Determina cual es página actual.
function initializer(){
    /* Supongase que la URL tiene la forma -- http://myweb.com/page1 -- */
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Obtener la URL y convertirlo en un arreglo
        let _url = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
        // En este caso _url[0] = 'mywebcom' y _url[1] = 'page1'

        //Ahora se determina que página se esta cargando y ejecutar
        // la o las funciones necesarias.
        if (_url[1] !== undefined) {
            switch (_url[1]) {
                case 'pagina1':
                    /* Función a ejecutar cuando se carga página1 */
                    refresh_automatico();
                    break;
                case 'pagina2':
                    /* Función a ejecutar cuando se carga página2 */
                    anotherFunction();
                    break;

            } //End-Switch
        } // End-If
    });
}

function refresh_automatico(){
    clearInterval(refreshId);
    var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
       load();
    }, 20000 );
}

function load(){
   /* Your load function */
   console.log('execute Function')
}
```

Eso es todo, espero sea lo que estés buscando y sobre todo te sea de utilidad.

==> Basado en tus comentarios, has intentado algo como:

```
function consultar(valor) { 
    conexion=crearXMLHttpRequest(); 
    conexion.onreadystatechange = procesarEventos; 
    conexion.open('GET', './redireccionador.php?num=' + valor, true); 

    if(valor == 'consultar_citas') {
        /* Si el parametro es consultar_citas realizar carga de la citas*/
        load()
    }

    conexion.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @LuiscYm, la cuestión es que estoy usando ajax para acceder a todas las paginas y cuando accedo a culquiera siempre me muestra la misma ruta: http://127.0.0.1/CoosaludWebhost/portal/index.php#  y asi no se como hacer para que me muestre la ruta con el script que estoy mandando a llamar por medio de ajax

Comment: Entiendo, podrías poner un ejemplo cuando haces la petición ajax a una página. Para tener una idea mas completa.

Comment: claro que si, tengo mi menu que es  <h2>Medicina General</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript: consultar('consultar_citas');">Mostrar Citas</a></li></ul>

Comment: luego tengo el ajax que recibe la funcion:  var conexion;
function crearXMLHttpRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp=null;
  if (window.ActiveXObject)
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  else
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  return xmlHttp;
}
function consultar(valor)
{
    conexion=crearXMLHttpRequest();
    conexion.onreadystatechange = procesarEventos;
    conexion.open('GET', './redireccionador.php?num=' + valor, true);
    conexion.send(null);
}

Comment: luego en el archivo redireccionador.php tengo esto  if ($_GET['num']=='consultar_citas')
  include ("consultar_cita.php");   y asi tengo todas mis paginas

Comment: Edité mi respuesta con una opción que podría ser de utilidad..

Comment: Correcto ya intenté como me dijiste y bien pero al momento de colocar la funcion de ejecucion automatica setInterval() y al pasar a otra, aun se sigue ejecutando: la hice asi

Comment: function consultar(valor)
{
    conexion=crearXMLHttpRequest();
    conexion.onreadystatechange = procesarEventos;
    conexion.open('GET', './redireccionador.php?num=' + valor, true);
    conexion.send(null);

    var refreshId = null;
    if(valor != 'consultar_citas') {
         clearInterval(refreshId);
    }else{

        var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
                 var pagina = $('#pagina').val();
                     load(pagina);
                 }, 20000 );
   }

}

Comment: Muchisimas gracias mi amigo LuisYm a usted y al compañero @alex55132 , mis respetos para ustedes muchachos, les debo una, muy agradecido con ustedes. me funciono todo a la perfeccion gracias a sus tips. Saludos muchachos

Answer (score 1):

Yo usaría algo así:

```
  //Declara la variable del intervalo de manera global para que aunque la definas en la funcion puedas acceder desde fuera
  var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
                 load();
             }, 20000 );
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
     clearInterval(refreshId);
     return "Hecho";
  };
```

Recalcar que según las [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) este evento debe devolver una string y que el codigo no lo he testeado

Comment: Muchas gracias @alex55132 , intente colocar el codigo que me indicaste pero nada, aun me sigue presentando el mismo problema, no se si es que lo estoy implementando mal o me falta algo por hacer

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé `window.onbeforeunload` tiene que estar fuera de la función, por ello digo que declare la variable refreshId de manera global para poder acceder a ella sin problema @luis_gomez

Comment: Gracias @alex55132 ya la declare global y cuando trato de usar clearInterval(refreshId); no me lo toma y me sigue ejecutando la funcion no se que pueda ser eso

Comment: Has comprobado si dentro de la funcion refreshId tiene algún valor? @luis_gomez

Comment: dentro tengo una variable que me traigo de la pagina: var pagina = $('#pagina').val();

Comment: No, quiero decir que si, cuando ejecutas la funcion `refresh_automatico()` la variable global `refreshId ` tiene algun valor o es null? @luis_gomez

Comment: Logrado @alex55132, gracias por su ayuda y su colaboracion, le debo una, ahora si puedo seguir trabajando. Mis respetos para usted

Comment: Si te ha funcionado marca la respuesta como correcta para poder ayudar a mas gente que tenga el mismo problema! Un saludo @luis_gomez

Comment: Correcto @alex55132, muchas gracias